# Time function return of only time

Tags: php, time

I know about the php time() function. But I just want it to return the current time. Nothing else.

`16:23`. No PM, no AM, no date, no seconds. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `date()`.

Comment: -1 for making absolutely no effort whatsoever to answer this yourself before asking here

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by format characters:

```
echo date("H:i");
```

look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).